# How to query the latest inserted item with Morphia

Tags: morphia

How to query the latest inserted item in with Morphia
And how to get the size of a collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you mean by latest, but if you have a Date field with the creation date then you would do this:

`T latest = ds.find().sort("-dateCreated").get();`

And this would get you the count:

`int count = ds.getCount(Class.class);`

Comment: In more recent versions of Morphia, the correspondent code is:
`ds.find(YourClass.class).order("-finishedAt").get()`

Comment: .order() looks good for me. I think that is what I am looking for... But it is Deprecated. What else should I use now?

Comment: Nowadays you would pass in a `FindOptions` object, with its `sort()` method having been called.  E.g., `new FindOptions().sort(descending("finishedAt"))`.

Answer (score 1):

When you save a document, the find method returns a object Key.
If you want to know your object with the key that morphia insert in database, just get the key and put in the object parameter. I'm doing this way in my application.

To sort can you just pass `.sort("dateCreated")` to sort in ASC, or `.sort("-dateCreated")` that sort for the DSC way.